# Convert appsettings.json section into Class

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I have a section ConnectionStringsConfiguration in my appsettings.json as following:

```
 {
      "AllowedHosts": "*",
      "ConnectionStringsConfiguration": {
        "test": {
          "ActiveEnvironment": "Development",
          "Development": "http://test:51080/test/",
          "Stage": "Stage connection string goes here",
          "Production": "Prod connection string goes here"
    }
  }
```

I am trying to read the section and cast it to a class:

```
public class ConfigurationMap
{
    public string ActiveEnvironment { get; set; }
    public string Development { get; set; }
    public string Stage { get; set; }
    public string Production { get; set; }
}
        var configuration = Builder();
        ConfigurationMap map = configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStringsConfiguration").GetSection("test").Get<ConfigurationMap>();
        ConnectionsConfiguration environment = map.ActiveEnvironment
            .ToEnum(ConnectionsConfiguration.Development);
```

I get map is null. What do I miss?

Comment: Was not able to repro.

Comment: Also note that `GetSection("ConnectionStringsConfiguration:test")` can be used instead of sequential calls.

Comment: What is `Builder`? Can you please add a [mre]?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do that. Use the following code to get any setting from appsettings.json file.

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;

namespace Solgen.Core
{
public static class CommonSettings
{
    public static IConfiguration AppSetting { get; }
    static CommonSettings()
    {
        AppSetting = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                .Build();
    }

    public static DateTime UtcToLocal(DateTime dateTime)
    {
        string timeZoneInfo = AppSetting["CommonSettings:DATE_TIMEZONE"]; 
        return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(dateTime, 
        TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(timeZoneInfo));
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this will help you. If you wish not to create a function you can simply use it like the following.

```
var link = CommonSettings.AppSetting["CommonSettings:GenerateLoanApplicationLocalLink"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this...

1. Create the required objects that will reflect the structure in your appsettings

   ```
   public class ConnectionStringsConfiguration
   {
      public TestConnectionStrings Test { get; set; }
   }

   public class TestConnectionStrings
   {
      public string ActiveEnvironment { get; set; }
      public string Development { get; set; }
      public string Stage { get; set; }
      public string Production { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. Get all of the required data from jou appsettings as a string

   ```
    var appSettingsPath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "appsettings.json");
      string appSettingsJson = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(appSettingsPath);
   ```
3. Deserialize the json

   ```
   ConnectionStringsConfiguration config = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ConnectionStringsConfiguration>(appSettingsJson );
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example:

```
var configuration  = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
    .Build();
ConfigurationMap map = configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStringsConfiguration")
    .GetSection("test")
    .Get<ConfigurationMap>();
```

Remark: A `}` is missing in your `appsettings.json`